# Xcode App is running slow, memory is very high

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app and is working great, except its too slow, I am running it on the debugger and the memory is running at 68.6MB to 75MB is that too high? If so, what are some tips to bring it down so my app runs a bit faster? I am using ShinobiGrids btw.

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/ios/shinobigrids

What my app does is makes a call to web service to get data and displays the data on a grid with a checkbox. When the user checks the checkbox the checking is delayed. I also have a datepicker and its also delayed when picking a date.

Just looking for some times on suggestions on what I can do.

Comment: Start by measuring things.  The Instruments application can show you memory allocations over time and let you decide whether there are things hanging around in memory that you don't need.  It also shows leaks, if any, and can be used to understand some timing issues too.

Comment: First of all code would be more significant for your question (for example : this section takes a long time to execute, why ? ). My guess is that you are waiting for web service response instead of making the server calls asynchronous. And 70mb is nothing, don't worry, you're not using too much memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and reduce all major tasks that would look like they would eat up memory...
70MB isn't a whole load of memory, but you can maybe check , if you're doing a RAM intensive task like adding a bunch of images to an array, 200 or so, and maybe displaying them as a GIF or something in an imageView, that would eat up a lot of memory. Try loading the data Asynchronously , more on that-

http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Working_Asynchronously_with_the_Remote_Data_Adapter_(Xcode)

If you have a whole load of variables and objects, maybe reduce them? You could try The  Allocations Instrument on xCode more on that here-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html

I'm attaching a tutorial on that below:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/finding-cause-of-simple-performance.html

Good luck anyway!

Comment: You're on the right track but how would you advise they find out what tasks are RAM Intensive and where the memory increase starts to pump up. There is a tool that you can use I am wondering if you can point that out in your answer otherwise your answer isn't really an answer as it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Popeye Thanks for reminding me about that! Forgot about the instruments, that was a really pertinent point!

Comment: Added additional information so I am happy to provide a +1